# Most efficient way to insert JSON objects from many files to MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, import, stream

I'm looking for the most efficient way to import JSON objects from a file to a MongoDB collection.

The files are looking like this:

```
[ { ... }, { ... } ]
```

with around 200 objects each file and with 100 files, so in sum 20.000 objects. I tried many approaches, many libraries...

My current working example is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const es = require('event-stream');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const glob = require('glob');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/inventory';

console.time('import');

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database) {
    const db = database.db('inventory');
    const collection = db.collection('storage');

    let importer = [];

    glob('../data/*.json', function (error, files) {
        files.forEach(function (filename) {
            importer.push(new Promise(function (resolve) {
                fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(JSONStream.parse('*')).pipe(es.map(function (document) {
                    collection.insertOne(document).then(resolve);
                }));
            }));
        });

        Promise.all(importer).then(function () {
            console.timeEnd('import');
        });
    });
});
```

It takes in average 20s (20074.834ms) on my local machine. Well, 20s are good, but I want to improve the performance here.

Comment: in my machine mongodb insert on average of 2000 docs in a sec try do some bulk inserts instead of insert one(like 100 for each chunk ). also if you don`t care about getting the results you can turn off the write Concern  to boost the write speed

Answer (score 0):

well this code is not fully optimized and i don`t do any error handling here but it suppose to reduce the time of the inserts.(your main bottleneck )

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const es = require('event-stream');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const glob = require('glob');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/inventory';

console.time('import');

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database) {
    const db = database.db('inventory');
    const collection = db.collection('storage');

    let importer = [];

    glob('../data/*.json', function (error, files) {
        files.forEach(function (filename) {
            const documents = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'));
            importer.push(collection.insertMany(documents),{w:0,ordered:false});
          });
        });

        Promise.all(importer).then(function () {
            console.timeEnd('import');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thx amit... I did some tests... I think the bottleneck is the reading operation, it took's in average 100ms per file.